# Копирование файла, сохраняя папки

Tags: php

В корне сайта есть папка `upload` и `tmp_upload`
При импорте данных из 1С приходят файлы в `tmp_upload`, и после обмена удаляются.

Файлы которые приходят, могут иметь такой вид:
`tmp_upload/f4/r33/5.pdf`
`tmp_upload/f4/5.pdf`
`tmp_upload/f4444/dfg/33/456/ff4/5.pdf`

Нужно переместить эти файлы в папку `upload`, сохраняя папки, в которых они находятся. По логике просто `tmp_upload/f4/5.pdf` заменился на `upload/f4/5.pdf`  и т.д.

Просто заменять название `tmp_upload` на `upload` не нужно.

Как можно переместить эти файлы, сохраняя структуру?

Comment: `system('cp -R upload/ tmp_upload/')` как то так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system('cp -R upload/ tmp_upload/')` в общем просто вызываем команду `cp -R src dstr`
где src - путь до источника dstr - путь назначения -R рекурсивно. Пути могут быть относительны но лучше использвать абсолютные.